# Encountering an I2C error 121 when interfacing an MPU6050 with a Raspberry Pi using Python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, i2c, mpu6050, iio

I am attempting to use an MPU6050 sensor with a Raspberry Pi, for the purpose of dectecting hte pitch, roll, and yaw of a DIY drone I'm building.

The MPU has worked in the past, somehow I've managed to change something in software, and I am now recieving the following error from my python script when I try to initialise the MPU:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/open-drone/Droneside/mpu.py", line 145, in <module>
    mpu.setUp() # Run MPU setuf functions
  File "/home/pi/open-drone/Droneside/mpu.py", line 56, in setUp
    self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x6B, 0x01)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

I have not changed the hardware connection to the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins since the sensor was last working, and the sensor is correctly detected on address 0x68 by `i2cdetect -y 1`:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

The relevant sections of code are shown below. I've trimmed these down a little to remove irrelevant print statements, and the multitude of variable initializations for the current pitch / yaw / roll etc.

```
class MPU: # Handels MPU
    def __init__(self, gyro, acc, tau):

        self.bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # Changing this to a '0' causes file not found error.
        self.address = 0x68
```

```
    def setUp(self):

        # Activate the MPU-6050
        self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x6B, 0x01) # Error occurs here.

        # Configure the accelerometer
        self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x1C, self.accHex)

        # Configure the gyro
        self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x1B, self.gyroHex)
```

```
mpu = MPU(gyro, acc, tau)
print("Waiting for I2C")
time.sleep(1) # This was a suggestion I saw from another post, didn't help.
print("Done waiting.")
mpu.setUp() # Run MPU setup functions

# Program does not get this far.

mpu.calibrateGyro(500) # Calibrate gyro w/ 500 pts, DRONE MUST BE LEVEL.
```

So far, I've tried inserting that one second delay shown in the last code block, which I saw suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735862/getting-ioerror-errno-121-remote-i-o-error-with-smbus-on-python-raspberry-w). Didn't help. Also tried a 10s delay, which made no difference.

I've tried changing the bus in `self.bus = smbus.SMBus(1)` to a '0', as I saw in a few other code examples, which just caused an file not found error.

I've also tried changing `self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x6B, 0x01)` to `self.bus.write_byte_data(self.address, 0x6B, 0x00)`, because I saw a couple of examples that had it that way, but that didn't work either.

Tried running everything with `sudo`, which didn't change anything, and I've checked that the I2C interface is enabled in `sudo raspiconfig`, it was already enabled.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: MPU6050 randomly started working again, briefly. I have made no changes to software of hardware. Whatever this problem is, it's causing the MPU to be unreliable, but not entirely non functional.

Comment: Why don;t you use the driver which is in the Linux kernel? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/imu/inv_mpu6050

Comment: Mostly because the rest of my software is in Python, and I'd rather keep it all in the one language. I suppose that could be worth a look as a last resort though. Do you (@0andriy) know of an easy way to make use of that driver with python? Perhaps by calling a command with subprocess?

Comment: Yes, the kernel driver use is preferred. In Python you can use it over direct accesses to sysfs or utilizing `libiio` (it has official Python bindings): https://analogdevicesinc.github.io/libiio/v0.24/python/index.html.  Note, most likely your distribution already packaged it for you and you only need to install the package.